# Easy way to move photos from Gmail attachment to Google Photos

Tags: gmail, google-photos

Is there a more intuitive way to add an attachment from GMail (either standard or Inbox) to Google Photos than saving it into the Google Photos folder in Google Drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Edit 2019: This answer is now out of date.

**Google Photos no longer synchronizes with Google Drive**. See the [official blog post](https://www.blog.google/products/photos/simplifying-google-photos-and-google-drive/).

---

It seems that you missed the news. Google Photos and Google Drive are now synchronized with each other. Check it on [Googleblog](http://googledrive.blogspot.com/2015/03/photosindrive.html) and [Google Help](https://support.google.com/photos/answer/6156103?hl=en)

Now you just need to save these attachments to Google Photos in Google Drive. Voila! Your images are automatically saved to Google Photos

Comment: Thanks, I know that, but I was wondering if there was a (more intuitive) way that does not involve three clicks and the selection of a folder in Google Drive (or a number of subfolders if one wants( or maybe this is even necessary?) to use the date-based folder structure of Google Photos).

Comment: Afaik, it's the most intuitive and easiest way. Since attachments are not in the universe of Google Photos, so you have to (1) manually download and add to Google Photos, or (2) add them to Google Drive with some clicks. I think date-based structure of Google Photos is still applicable in either way.

Comment: @Ralphilius can you describe the 2nd option plz.

Comment: @Vincent If you hovered over an attachment, you will see a Drive icon. Clicking on that will save the attachment to Drive.

Comment: I've downloaded some pictures as an email attachment to Google Drive and they are not showing up in Google Photos. Does this automatic sync process have a delay, or is some further action required?

Comment: And how will it affect my quota, if I save in corresponding "Photos" folder in google drive?

Comment: Agreed! This is not the answer. Saving photos on Google Drive and putting photos on Google Photos is not the same at all. Saving photos to Drive might make them show up in Photos but they will occupy space in Drive, whereas photos in Photos do not.

Comment: Actually I think photos saved to the special "Google Photos" folder in Google Drive do *not* occupy space. See the other answer for how to create the special Google Photos folder in Google Drive: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/101471/10362

Comment: @WillSheppard Photos do occupy space when saved this way because they have their "original quality." It's important to clarify Google's policy of "high quality" vs "original quality" : https://support.google.com/photos/answer/6220791?hl=en -- that said, it's possible to "recover" the space taken by these photos by using https://photos.google.com/settings and clicking the Recover button. Uploading photos (as opposed to saving them to Google Drive) will apply the selected policy (original vs. high quality). I just did a test and saving photos did NOT change their original size.

Comment: Another disadvantage of this method (as opposed to saving to .zip and uploading individual photos) is that there is no automatic classification by date.

Answer (score 0):

Login to your Google Drive account. Then press preferences button. You will see 'Create A Folder For Google Photos'. Check it enable. And now go to your Gmail account and open a mail including photos. Add it to Google Drive first. Then press organize button and move the photo to new Google Photos folder.