# Automated way to move Gmail image / video attachments to Google Photos

Tags: gmail, google-photos, gmail-attachments

I'm running out of storage in my Google account. In order to save space, I'm trying to move many images and videos from Gmail into Google Photos with "high quality" (where [Google Photos offers unlimited storage](https://support.google.com/photos/answer/6220791?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)).

I know this can be done manually with some help from [Google One storage management](https://one.google.com/storage/management), but I'm looking for a way to automate a batch process of finding all image / video attachments in emails, uploading them to Google Photos, and deleting them from Gmail, while preserving the email thread.

Ideal outcome would be:

1. Image and video attachments deleted from Gmail
2. All text in emails preserved
3. Image and video attachments uploaded to Google Photos
4. links to the location of the attachments included in the email thread (in a way that doesn't send an email to anyone else in the conversation or move the message back to my inbox)

If not all of this is possible, automating some of the items would be helpful. If there's a script that does some of the work that I could modify, that could be a solution.

Things I've looked into already:

1. [Gmail support: How can I move photo attachments in my email to
   Google Photos or Google Drive?](https://support.google.com/mail/thread/10560788?hl=en)
2. [Stack exchange question: Easy
   way to move photos from Gmail attachment to Google Photos](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/78960/easy-way-to-move-photos-from-gmail-attachment-to-google-photos/78983)
3. [Chrome extension: Save Image to Google Photo](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/save-image-to-google-phot/djakijfdccnmmnknpmphdkkjbjfenkne/related?q=gmail)

Comment: If you are looking for an existing software that does this I suggest you to post a question on [softwarerecs.se].

Comment: [Google Photos is only offering unlimited storage for new uploads up until 1 June 2021.](https://blog.google/products/photos/storage-changes)

Answer (score 1):

From the question

> 1. Image and video attachments deleted from Gmail
> 2. All text in emails preserved
> 4. links to the location of the attachments included in the email thread (in a way that doesn't send an email to anyone else in the conversation or move the message back to my inbox)

This can't be done using the Gmail web app, mobile apps, Google Apps Script / Gmail API, but might be done using an email-client program / script that use IMAP.

> 3. Image and video attachments uploaded to Google Photos

This can be done using Google Backup and Sync. I don't think that the Photos API could be used to upload images without consuming storage quotas.

Related (oldest first)

- [Replace Gmail attachments with Dropbox/Google Drive download link](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/49823/88163)
- [Can one delete a Gmail attachment but keep the email?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/95427/88163)
- [fastest way to upload google photos (unlimited storage)](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/116141/88163)
- [Is there a way to convert gmail attachments to gmail docs, and replace them in the message with links to the drive file?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/137612/88163)

Resources

- [Introducing Backup and Sync for Google Photos and Google Drive](https://www.blog.google/products/photos/introducing-backup-and-sync-google-photos-and-google-drive/)